# Invalid link crashes in integration test instead of producing a flash error message

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, testing, integration-testing

In an integration test I have:

```
get activation_path("invalid token")
assert flash[:danger]
assert_redirected_to root_path
```

The `activation_path` refers to a path where a token gets validated. A correct path would look like: `get activation_path("valid token", inv: '10')`. So in the test, the link does not contain a value for `inv` and thus is an invalid link. The controller method uses the `inv` to find the invitation:

```
@invitation = Invitation.find(params[:inv])
```

So the expected behavior is that the invalid link produces a flash error and a redirect. However, the first line of the test fails with as error:

> ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound: Couldn't find Invitation with 'id'=

This refers to the *first* line of the controller method, which as mentioned is:

```
@invitation = Invitation.find(params[:inv])
```

Why is the test failing? I would expect it to just return `nil` for `@invitation` but instead it generates the error. How should I adjust (the controller method?) to take into account users submitting such invalid links?

**Update:** I've also tried:

```
get activation_path("valid token", inv: '88888888888')
assert flash[:danger]   # There's no invitation with that number
assert_redirected_to root_path
```

This test as well fails pointing to the same first line of the controller method:

> ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound: Couldn't find Invitation with an out
>   of range value for 'id'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per the [Rails docs](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#retrieving-a-single-object):

> The find method will raise an ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound exception
>   if no matching record is found.

By default, Rails responds to an `ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound` error by rendering a 404 response in production and staging. This is typically the desired response when a user visits a URL for a non-existent record.

If you want it to return `nil` instead of raising an error, use `find_by_id` instead:

```
Invitation.find_by_id 0
=> nil
```